# Commutative subring of matrices iff trivial unit group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and let $T := \left\{\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & c\end{bmatrix} \in \text{Mat}_2(R) \mid a,b,c \in R\right\}$. I have shown that $T$ is a subring of $M_2(R)$ which is noncommutative for $R ≠ \{0\}$, and $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & c\end{bmatrix} \in T^* \iff \{a,c\} \subseteq R^*.$$

Now it should also be true that $T^*$ is abelian if and only if $R^* = \{1\}$. Now of course you can, assuming $T^*$ is abelian, take two arbitrary elements $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & c\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}x & y \\ 0 & z\end{bmatrix} \in T^*$ and derive the necessary equalities $ax = xa, ay+bz = xb+yc$ and $cz = zc$, but I don't see how that would imply that $R$ has a trivial unit group. Another attempt would be to assume that $R^* \setminus \{1\} ≠ \emptyset$, let $u \in R^* \setminus \{1\}$ and consider some products like 
$$\begin{bmatrix}u & 1 \\ 0 & u\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u & 0 \\ 0 & u\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then you'd see that $u^2 = 1$, but not necessarily that $u = 1$.
It seems there should be a smarter argument.

Comment: @user26857: It is perfectly fine to talk about whether the multiplicative **group** of units of a ring is abelian or not. The adjective “abelian” is not modifying the ring, it is modifying a multiplicative group.

Comment: @user26857: Oh, I see; I read the body, which only used "abelian" to refer to the group of units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close; you just aren't taking the right products.

Suppose $u\in R^*$, and consider the invertible matrices
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}u&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \left(\begin{array}{cc}u^{-1}&0\\0&1\end{array}\right).$$

If $T^*$ is abelian, then the two products are equal, so
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
u&1\\
0 &1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
u^{-1}&0\\0&1\end{array}\right) &= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\\
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
u^{-1}&0\\
0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
u&1\\
0&1\end{array}\right) &= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & u^{-1}\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right),
\end{align*}$$
hence $u^{-1}=1$.

Comment: Thanks. I see now that the converse holds as well. This can easily be deduced by using the implication $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & c\end{bmatrix} \in T^* \Rightarrow \{a,c\} \subseteq R^*$.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman: Yes, the other implication is pretty straightforward.